Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' doesn't belong to resolved component
I have some issues when importing a KMM library into an Android native project. It looks like it's unable to find a proper variant to implement in the Android native project.
This is the gradle error:

Variant 'jvmApiElements-published' doesn't belong to resolved component 'com.example.app:modulo_da_pubblicare:1.0.0-389'.
A variant with the same name exists but is not the same instance.
Most likely you are using a variant from another component to get the dependencies of this component.

Here is the gradle file that I am using for publishing:
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") // kotlin_version
    alias(libs.plugins.pluginSerialization)
    id(libs.plugins.maven.publish.get().pluginId)
}

group = "org.openapitools"
version = "1.0.0"

val kotlin_version = "1.9.20"
val coroutines_version = "1.7.3"
val serialization_version = "1.6.1"
val ktor_version = "2.3.6"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serialization_version")

                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
                api("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")

            }
        }

        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7"))
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:$ktor_version")
            }
        }

        all {
            languageSettings.apply {
                optIn("kotlin.Experimental")
            }
        }
    }
}

val appId: String by project
val appVersionName: String by project
val appVersionCode: String by project
publishing {
    publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
        groupId = "com.example.apiModule"
        artifactId = "apiModule"
        version = "$appVersionName-$appVersionCode"
    }

    repositories {
        // https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:preemptive_authentication
        maven {
            name = "COMPANY_NAME"
            url = uri("https://myrepo.com/repository/maven-releases/")
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("REPO_USER")
                password = System.getenv("REPO_PWD")
            }
            authentication {
                create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
            }
        }
    }
}

Do you have any suggestion on resolution?
